# How to edit symbols in categorized symbol renderers using PyQGIS?

Tags: pyqgis, symbology

I have a QGIS project with various point and line layers, some with a categorized symbology and one line layer with line markers. I'm trying to create a simple Python script to quickly change the size/width of the point/line markers in all of these layers, in order to be able to make clear maps. My script currently looks like this:

```
from qgis.core import QgsProject

# Enter scaling factor here
scale_factor = 2

# Symbol scaling function
def scale_symbol(scl, sym, lrn, ind):
    new_symbol = sym.clone()
    
    # Change size of point symbols
    if new_symbol.type() == QgsSymbol.Marker:
        new_symbol.setSize(new_symbol.size() * scl)
        print("Symbol rescaled for layer", lrn[ind])
        print("New symbol size:",new_symbol.size(), new_symbol.outputUnit())
        
    # Change width of line symbols
    elif new_symbol.type() == QgsSymbol.Line:
        new_symbol.setWidth(new_symbol.width() * scl)
        print("Symbol rescaled for layer", lrn[ind])
        print("New symbol width:",new_symbol.width(), new_symbol.outputUnit())
        
        # Change size of line marker symbols
        if new_symbol.symbolLayerCount() > 1:
            marker_layer = new_symbol.symbolLayer(1)
            marker_layer.setWidth(marker_layer.width() * scl)
            print("Symbol rescaled for layer", lrn[ind], "(markers)")
            print("New symbol size:",marker_layer.width(), new_symbol.outputUnit())
    
    return new_symbol


project = QgsProject.instance()
# List of layers to be rescaled
layer_names = ['Leidingen_PLAN', 'Putten_PLAN', 'Leiding', 'Put', 'Lozing_Inlaat', 'HC_ref_deksel']

# Get renderer for each layer
renderer_list = []
for layer_name in layer_names:
    layer = project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
    renderer_list.append(layer.renderer())

idx = 0
for renderer in renderer_list:
    print(renderer.type())
            
    # Rescale single symbol layers
    if renderer.type() == 'singleSymbol':
        symbol = renderer.symbol()
        new_symbol = scale_symbol(scale_factor, symbol, layer_names, idx)
        renderer.setSymbol(new_symbol)
     
    # Rescale categorized symbol layers 
    elif renderer.type() == 'categorizedSymbol':
        categories = renderer.categories()
        
        # Loop over symbols of all categories 
        for category in categories: 
            symbol = category.symbol()
            new_symbol = scale_symbol(scale_factor, symbol, layer_names, idx)
            category.setSymbol(new_symbol)
        
    idx += 1
```

This script works for the single symbol layers (of which I can see the markers change size after running the script), but not for the categorized symbol layers. No error is raised, the `print` statements show that all renderers, categories and layers are being handeled and their sizes and widths should be changed. Does the `.setSymbol()` method not affect the symbols when  they are in a category of a categorized renderer instead of directly in a renderer? Then what is the correct way to set a new symbol for a categorized symbol layer using PyQGIS? (I'm also open to suggestions for other convenient methods that allow me to change the symbol size for multiple layers at once.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the method [updateSymbols()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer.html#a2beb679ea8e9941edc1e4edaad490c8a) of the `QgsCategorizedSymbolRenderer` class.

With this method, you can change the marker size/ line width while leaving the colours and categories unmodified.

So your script could look like:

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

# Enter scaling factor here
scale_factor = 2

# Symbol scaling function
def scale_symbol(scl, sym, lrn, ind):
    new_symbol = sym.clone()
    
    # Change size of point symbols
    if new_symbol.type() == QgsSymbol.Marker:
        new_symbol.setSize(new_symbol.size() * scl)
        print("Symbol rescaled for layer", lrn[ind])
        print("New symbol size:",new_symbol.size(), new_symbol.outputUnit())
        
    # Change width of line symbols
    elif new_symbol.type() == QgsSymbol.Line:
        new_symbol.setWidth(new_symbol.width() * scl)
        print("Symbol rescaled for layer", lrn[ind])
        print("New symbol width:",new_symbol.width(), new_symbol.outputUnit())
        
        # Change size of line marker symbols
        if new_symbol.symbolLayerCount() > 1:
            marker_layer = new_symbol.symbolLayer(1)
            marker_layer.setWidth(marker_layer.width() * scl)
            print("Symbol rescaled for layer", lrn[ind], "(markers)")
            print("New symbol size:",marker_layer.width(), new_symbol.outputUnit())
    
    return new_symbol

project = QgsProject.instance()
# List of layers to be rescaled
layer_names = ['Leidingen_PLAN', 'Putten_PLAN', 'Leiding', 'Put', 'Lozing_Inlaat', 'HC_ref_deksel']

idx = 0

for layer_name in layer_names:
    layers = project.mapLayersByName(layer_name)
    
    if not layers:
        print(f'Layer {layer_name} not found')
        continue
        
    layer = layers[0]
    
    renderer = layer.renderer()
    # Rescale single symbol layers
    if renderer.type() == 'singleSymbol':
        symbol = renderer.symbol()
        new_symbol = scale_symbol(scale_factor, symbol, layer_names, idx)
        renderer.setSymbol(new_symbol)
     
    # Rescale categorized symbol layers 
    elif renderer.type() == 'categorizedSymbol': 
        symbol = renderer.sourceSymbol()
        new_symbol = scale_symbol(scale_factor, symbol, layer_names, idx)
        renderer.updateSymbols(new_symbol)
    
    layer.triggerRepaint()
    iface.layerTreeView().refreshLayerSymbology(layer.id())
    
    idx += 1
```